# Mostrar solo los campos checkados de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola necesito  hacer una funcion que se encargue de mostrar solo los campos checkados.
La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
 input#Solocheck(type='checkbox',onchange='solo_check(this)')
                | &nbsp&nbspVer seleccionados

 table#tblusuariosb.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-bordered.table-condensed.table-fixed(style='font-size:14px')
        thead(style="font-size:14px;background-color:rgb(232,232,232);")
            tr(style='background-color:rgb(242,242,242);')
                th(style='width:5%;text-align:center;') 
                    input.Tusuarios.noExl(type='checkbox',onchange='seleccion_todocheck(this)')
                th Usuario
                th Perfil            
            tbody(style="height:290px; ")
                each val in datos.usuarios.rows
                    tr                         
                        td(style='width:5%;text-align:center;')
                            input.check.noExl(type='checkbox', value='#{val.pk}', data-bono=val.bonos, onchange="disableButton(this)")
                        td #{val.u}                   
                        td #{val.p}                    
                        td.pkusuarios(data-pkusu=''+val.pk, style='display:none;') #{val.pk}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta seria la estructura de la tabla

Y lo que necesito es que al hacer click al check de ver seleccionados en automatico solo me muestre los registros de pedro luis y karla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún framework? Deberías mencionarlo, pues no me parece Javascript o jQuery convencional.

Comment: Amm el codigo que se muestra ahi es solo para dar la estructura de la tabla principal. Aun no tengo codigo en si para la funcion que necesito. Solo muestro el codigo con el que "Armo la tabla"

Comment: Al marcar el check, buscas partiendo de todos los checks no marcados el `tr` padre y lo ocultas, por ejemplo:   `$('.table_check:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide()`   Quizá sea más flexible hacerlo con ul/li que con tables... pero eso va al gusto del programador, la idea de fondo será la misma.  *(Aquí asumo que los checks tienen la clase `table_check`)*